# padding issue in bootstrap with fullpage.js

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I have webpage where I have implemented `fullpage.js` but the issue is there is `padding-left` and `padding-right` automatically added at `container-fluid` if I remove that,there is some white spaces on the left. This problem comes only when I add `rows` inside the `container-fluid`

**html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="row section" id="home">HomePage</div>
        <div class="row section" id="products">Products</div>
        <div class="row section" id="pricing">Pricing</div>
        <div class="row section" id="contact">Contact</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

PS:Using bootstrap 4

Comment: add snippet or live link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.container`s are meant to work together with `.row`s in Bootstrap. They have a clever system involving margins and paddings that cancel each other but make it look good on all devices.

***Easiest way around that would be to place `.container-fluid` inside  `#fullpage`***, not the other way around.

***As an alternative***, if, for various reasons, you'd rather not (or cannot) change the markup, you could transfer the negative margins from `.row`s to `#fullpage`:

```
#fullpage {
   margin-left: -15px;
   margin-right: -15px;
}
#fullpage>.row {
   margin-left: 0;
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: this was it. Thanks bud :)